# Wcf web service openration timeout

Tags: wcf, web-services, webservice-client, execution

If I am calling webservice asynchrnously on asp.net web page. And once submitting request to webservice I am able to close browser as I dont need to web service return any result to asp.net page. So what I want is that how can I increase time out of webservice execution which internally execute function which is taking more than 2-3 hourse to execute abd update in db.
So my objective of making web service independent of asp.net page is satisfied but I just want to know to increase time out of web service. Can I difine it in web.config of web service?

Answer (score 1):

You can use below code to achieve this:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<services>
    <service name="OrderService">
        <endpoint address=""
        contract="MyNamespace.IOrderService"
        binding="WsHttpBinding"
        bindingConfiguration="CloseTimeout">
        </endpoint>
    </service>
</services>
<bindings>
    <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="CloseTimeout" closeTimeout="03:00:00">
        </binding>
    </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: I want to increse operation time out at server side as I am using one way call so no need to increase open and close timeout at client side.

Comment: Why don't you use a singleton instance of your service?  This will it wont expire...